# How to lock network operator or to never go on roaming, or get out of roaming as soon as possible

Tags: reboot, mobile-network, roaming

I work really close to a country border, and I do NOT want my phone to connect to other operators than mine.

Sometimes the operator from my home country will be unavailable for a brief period of time, and the phone will go on roaming. (and it's useless. no phone, no sms, no web. pointless)

When I'm back in a zone where my home country operator has coverage, the phone will stick to roaming for a good while (hours), and I have to notice it and manually select my operator.

Unfortunately when the phone reboots the "choose automatically" option is re-set, so if I reboot the phone (or when it reboots itself), I have to do this again.

I have tasker, but didn't find a way. I am also ready to root the phone if needed.
I just don't know how to select a network operator and prevent the phone to switch to "choose automatically" at every reboot. It's not about apn and roaming charges, I just want it to never go on roaming ever ever ever.

Any suggestion?

(device info: OnePlus One, android 5.0.1, cyanogenmod cm12)

Comment: Setting the operator manually would just be the thing to do – it shouldn't revert that on boot. Could you please [edit] your question and include your device and its Android version? As for *Tasker*: According to [my flowchart](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) (scroll down on that page), there should be something in *Action › Settings › Network Operator*. Can you check that?

Comment: I am quite sure that the operator setting revert on boot. At least until my last upgrade to CM12 (I was in CM11 and I rebooted it so many times that I am sure that that was the problem). Now in CM12 it connected a few times to roaming even if I switched manually, so I think it's due to reboots that revert my options.
Also: on tasker when I choose the "network operator" action, I have a screen with "If   +   Label" and I don't know how to set the operator from there

Comment: running the tasker "network operator" action triggers the "choose network" application, where I have to manually choose the operator. This is severely suboptimal, but if only I could trigger it when the phone detect that it is going on roaming..

Comment: ok. a (severely suboptimal) workaround is to use tasker, detect if %ROAM equals "on", and launch the action "network operator" that opens the opeator selection setting page.

Comment: You might utilize the "execute command" action here and run `setprop gsm.sim.operator.numeric <value>` (not tested, but worth a try). To get the wanted value, set the operator manually once, and then run `getprop gsm.sim.operator.numeric` (you can do so e.g. via `adb shell`). Not sure about the effects, but worth a try. References: [1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1159641) | [2](http://www.modaco.com/topic/304693-market-enabler-workaround/) | [3](https://code.google.com/p/market-enabler/wiki/ShellCommands).

Comment: PS: If that works, also [see here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-epic-4g/83436-sprint-us-cellular-epic.html#post1191557)

Comment: No: I tried in every possible way. The operator cannot be set by setprop gsm.sim.operator.numeric in any way. The manual selection reverts on boot. There's no solution to this problem, yet.

Comment: If it's just the "reset on boot", you could put that statement into a shell script and place it in `/system/etc/init.d` to be executed on boot. Might also work with a `build.prop` modification – though I'm not sure whether that'd be a wise decision (what if you're planning vacation abroad?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Android M Marshmallow does fix this bug.

I am now running Android 6.0.1, CyanogenMod version 13, and the operator does not revert back to automatic-selection anymore after reset.

The exact CyanogemMod version I am running is: 13.0-ZNH2K-20160430-STABLE-Sultan-bacon.